# Proxy server with Vite and Axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, proxy, vite

I have problem with using proxy when I am trying to run production version of my application. When I use proxy with `vite` command (development command to start Vite project), It works without problems. I can change target URL and it works. But when I build project with `vite build` and then run with `serve -s dist`, It doesnt work.

My axios config:
[image]

My vite.config.js:
[image]

Error in console:
[image]

When I try this with dev script (`code`), everything works.. I can even change URL with ENV variable and then my frontend using another backend (I have 2 backends live to debug this). It only doesnt work in production mode with command `serve -s dist`. Any ideas?

I also noticed, that when I change baseUrl in axios config, it works with this url.. so It is something with proxy and production version..

EDIT:
I noticed, that requests to that URL ending up with status code 200 OK, but the preview tab in google dev tools is white screen..

Comment: You can check what happens with requests in dev tools. If url is correct but response isn't then it's server side to blame. It's not obvious from the question if you know this, but there is no proxy in prod, unless you set it up yourself apart from vite setup - through nginx, etc. Btw there's localStorage['...'] on the screenshot, this is a mistake, this is not how values are retrieved from LS